# Adding something to jna.library.path on OSX

Tags: macos, rococoa

I need to added a bin directory to jna.library.path to get Rococoa working on OSX but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.  Inside java when I call System.getProperty("jna.library.path"); it returns null so this won't give me a clue about where to place the bin directory.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

java -Djna.library.path=path\to\bin

Comment: this was the command I tried:
java -Djna.library.path=Library/Java/Extensions/bin

Comment: Well, you have to add this option when you call the program, so java -Djna.library.path ClassName. If you run it from Eclipse or NetBeans, open options dialog for running the program and add -D(..) to the VM parameters.